# How to load multible menus with jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm using a jquery tabs menu to load content via ajax in the panel.
This is my code:

```
    <head><script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                "error" );
                });
            }
        });
        });
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="tabs">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Startseite</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">FAQ</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-style">
    <h1> content</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit am...... tristique eget, accumsan eget quam. </p>

  </div><div class="footer"><ul><li><a href="ajax/agb.php" id ="link">AGB</a></li></ul>


  </div>
```

The menu above works fine and the tab's content is loaded correctly within the panel.
But by clicking a link in the footer menu, it leaves the page.

I've already tried the following :

```
<div class="footer"><ul><li><a href="#" id ="link">AGB</a></li></ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#link').click(function() {
          $('#tabs').load('agb.php');
     });
</script>
  </div>
```

because I need also a solution for links in the content panels, but this also does not work. Hope you can help me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: The jQuery UI code, looks to be fine according to the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax). Are your sure that you've included jQueryUI and jQuery ?

Comment: yes i did tabs are working fine in the menu above.
And you're right, this is my first try with jqueryUI tabs.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs').load('agb.php');
});
```

Comment: ok this loads agb.php in my panel, but then it just loads the agb.php and the menu above and footer disappears. I can redefine this in the content pages, but is there a way, that it behaves like the links in the tab menu above, so that there is no need to redefine the tab menu and footer.

With this way I also need for every link an ID with it's own Javascript block, is there a solution that I can apply to every link in the content panel.

Comment: You can offcourse provide a class for each link you want to hook into the tab system. Then you can do something like $('.tablink').click().


Are you sure the php page returns a valid html that can be 'injected' in the tabcontrol?

Comment: Hmm yes my agb.php returns valid HTML , without body, html or doctype declarations like in the jqueryui example. The menu is not Do i have to give the footer an own id to behave like a tab link? Everytime i click links there, the agb is injected in the tabs container, but the menu and the footer are not displayed then anymore.

To the class for links, well i can give every link an own class but how can i do this function variable or how i can give the link to the function like: $('#tabs').load(varLink);

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery callbacks, return `false` to have the default action prevented.  The default action for a link is to navigate to the location of the `href` attribute.

```
 $('#link').click(function() {
      $('#tabs').load('agb.php');
      return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tabs').load('agb.php');
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your footer links you could do that :

```
$('.footer a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs').load(link);
});
```

If you wanted to do it on all the links, bind the click event on every link :

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) { ... });
```